# How to modify $(this) as the parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following HTML and JS files:

HTML

```
<div>
  <p id="myId">Hello World</p>
  <button class="myClass" name="aNewName" OnClick=display(this)>my button</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function display(el){
    $('#myId').text($(el).attr('name'));
}
```

how can I call display() function with "this" as the parameter, but with a modified 'name' attribute? The reason for my question is that I want to call "display" function from another script but without an onclick event. I just need to pass different attributes to it.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking: `function display(el, attrName) { $('#myId').text($(el).attr(attrName)); }` `display($("#myId"), "name")` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m please see my comment under Rory McCrossan's answer below. I tried to clear up my question.

Comment: Add another parameter, as in my example above.

Comment: you're right, I think I should modify the way I call the function. I thought there might be a way to create an object that contains all those attributes and can be treated as "this" by the function.

Comment: That would be @RoryMcCrossan solution of using `.call(objectToBeThis)`.  But it's much harder to determine what that object should be compared with calling to clearly named parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the scope of a function invocation use the `call()` method:

```js
function display() {
  $('#myId').text($(this).attr('name'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="myId">Hello World</p>
  <button class="myClass" name="aNewName" onclick="display.call(this)">my button</button>
</div>
```

***However*** I'd argue that performing your logic in this way is completely missing the point of unobtrusive JS/jQuery. A better approach would be to not use the inline event handler at all. For example, here's an unobtrusive example in plain JS:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Note this assumes only 1 .myClass element is in the DOM
  document.querySelector('.myClass').addEventListener('click', e => document.querySelector('#myId').innerText = e.target.name);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="myId">Hello World</p>
  <button class="myClass" name="aNewName">my button</button>
</div>
```

Here is the same thing in jQuery:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.myClass').on('click', e => $('#myId').text(e.target.name));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="myId">Hello World</p>
  <button class="myClass" name="aNewName">my button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think my question is how would you simulate (this) if you want to invoke 'Display()' function from a 'non-OnClick' event? In the code I showed above, I'm invoking 'Display()' from an onClick event inside a button tag. How do you call the same function from, lets say an if statement in the javaScript file, by passing a parameter that 'Display' can accept as (this) ? A parameter that holds the attribute "name". @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Please let me know if I need to ask my question in a more clear way.

Comment: It's not clear what your use case is, however `call()` can still be used.

Comment: About my use case: I need to call Display() from a javaScript file. If I was calling it using an on-click(), I could pass "this" which holds all the attributes inside the button tag. Now that I want to call it again, but this time from inside JS, I don't know how I should pass a parameter that holds all those attributes. Your solution works if the function is called from HTML. Am I right? @Rory McCrossan